# Boundary Fill Algorithm in Opengl

Tags: c, algorithm, opengl, boundary

The algorithm goes into recursion. It prints out blue lines on the polygon but at a particular location (X=397,Y=98). The color doesn't get printed at the pixel and then goes into a recursion for the same pixel and its neighbors.

```
#include<GL/gl.h>
#include<GL/glu.h>
#include<GL/glut.h>

typedef struct pixel{ GLubyte red, green, blue; } pixel;



void boundaryfill(float x,float y, pixel fill, pixel boundary)
{
  pixel c;
  glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &c);
 // printf("%d,%d,%d",(int)c.red,(int)c.green,(int)c.blue);
  if ((c.red!=boundary.red)&&(c.red!=boundary.blue)&&(c.green!=boundary.green)&&(c.green!=fill.green)&&(c.blue!=fill.blue)&&(c.red!=fill.red)&&\
(x<=400))//&&(y<=100)&&(y>=50)&&(x>=200))
    {

      glBegin(GL_POINTS);
      glColor3ub(fill.red,fill.green,fill.blue);
      glVertex2f(x,y);
      glEnd();
      glFlush();
      glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &c);
      printf("\nCOlOR %d,%d,%d",(int)c.red,(int)c.green,(int)c.blue);
      printf("\nX=%f,Y=%f",x,y)

          //                                                                                                                             
      boundaryfill(x+1,y,fill,boundary);
      boundaryfill(x-1,y,fill,boundary);
      boundaryfill(x,y+1,fill,boundary);
      boundaryfill(x,y-1,fill,boundary);

    }

}

void mydisplay()
{
      glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
      glColor3ub(10,10,10);
      glVertex2f(200,50);
      glVertex2f(200,100);
      glVertex2f(400,100);
      glVertex2f(400,50);
      glEnd();
      glFlush();
      pixel fill,boundary;
      fill.red=0;
      fill.green=0;
      fill.blue=255;
      boundary.red=255;
      boundary.green=255;
      boundary.blue=255;
      boundaryfill(300,75,fill,boundary);
      glEnd();
      glFlush();
}

void main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  glutInit(&argc,argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
  glutInitWindowSize(400,400);
  glutInitWindowPosition(540,320);
  glutCreateWindow("my first attempt");
  glClearColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0,0.0f);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glutDisplayFunc(mydisplay);

  gluOrtho2D(0.0,400.0,0.0,400.0);
  glutMainLoop();


}
```

Comment: Even if you can get this to work, it's going to be horribly inefficient. You aren't meant to call glReadPixels millions of times in a row!

Comment: The problem I am facing is that it draws a line on the polygon which extends beyond the screen. Then when I add x<=400 , then the line extends upward on the boundary at 400 and goes into the white background (print the commented line with COLOR). The boundary fill algorithm was defined this way. Is there anything missing.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that you're overflowing the stack due to infinite recursion. What prevents the program from just calling `boundaryfill` forever?

Also, you're missing a call to `glEnd` inside `boundaryfill`, but I suspect that's not the reason for the crash.